# java application that can run automatically from a web server

Tags: java

I need to upload a java application in a web server that can start automatically, execute and stop every 1 hour or an interval provided by me. How can i do it ?
I have tried creating such an application in windows. But will it work automatically from an web server ? What will be the trigger that would start the application automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the scheduler, there are various types of schedulers available in Java, If you are using spring you can use the spring integrated schedulers, or there are APIs available for this, for example

```
http://quartz-scheduler.org/
```

This is a well known API, which allows you to run scheduler as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Which web server are you using?
In JBOSS we can do auto deployment by creating a file named WAR_NAME.dodeploy for WAR_NAME.war file.

On a high level, we can define the time interval and a program to auto deploy the war file on web server.

Same for stopping too.. but it is web server specific.